Python: Package installed with meson cannot be found by pip
I have been trying to solve an issue compiling a Python package for Windows, and part of that involves building contourpy in the UCRT64 environment on MSYS2. I have been able to successfully build the package in virtualenv using the following commands:
$ python -m virtualenv ~/envs/contourpy
$ source ~/envs/contourpy/bin/activate

# Compile contourpy
$ git clone https://github.com/contourpy/contourpy.git
$ cd contourpy
$ meson setup builddir
$ ninja -C builddir
$ meson install -C builddir --destdir /home/guest/envs/contourpy

These options allow me to build contourpy successfully. However when I try running pip list, it doesn't show up in this environment.
When I try to run pip install . directly, I get the following error messages:
      Found ninja.EXE-1.11.1.git.kitware.jobserver-1 at C:/msys64/tmp/pip-build-env-0ba4jhpg/normal/bin/ninja.EXE

      Visual Studio environment is needed to run Ninja. It is recommended to use Meson wrapper:
      C:/msys64/tmp/pip-build-env-0ba4jhpg/overlay/bin/meson compile -C .
      + meson compile --ninja-args=['-v']

Is there a way I can get this package to perform the compilation while using pip install .?

Does pip install . not work?

Why do you need to use meson? The documentation, including the developer documentation, suggests to just use pip install. The actual build happens under the hood (use --verbose to see the compiler commands).

Thanks for raising those queries. I've added the error I get when running pip install . to the question as well.

I managed to resolve the issue.
In the pyproject.toml file in the repo, the following line needs to be commented out:
...
[tool.meson-python.args]
compile = [
    "-v",
]
dist = []
install = []
setup = [
    # "--vsenv",  # Forces use of MSVC on Windows, ignored on other platforms
]
...

The UCRT64/MSYS2 environment doesn't appear to support MSVC (or I might have missed out on installing the compilers), resulting in the meson-python running in the backend failing. Disabling this line allows pip install . for contourpy to work on UCRT64/MSYS2.
